# Is there a function $f\in H(\mathbb{D})\cap C(\bar{\mathbb{D}}) $ with the following property

Tags: complex-analysis

> > Is there a function $f\in H(\mathbb{D})\cap C(\bar{\mathbb{D}})$, such that $f(z)|_{\partial \mathbb{D}}=x^2+yi$
> >     test where $\mathbb{D}$ is a unit disk?

In fact, I am confused about the meaning "test where $\mathbb{D}$ is a unit disk", in my view, I think the question wants to say that

> > Is there a function  $f\in H(\mathbb{D})\cap C(\bar{\mathbb{D}})$, such that $f(z)|_{\partial \mathbb{D}}=x^2+yi$
> >     while $\mathbb{D}$ is a unit disk?

I failed to know whether my understanding is right or not, could someone can help me out? If it is right, and where can I START with the problem? Sincerely thanks!

Comment: You may want to check the sections on Poisson integral in some complex analysis book.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word "test" is there by mistake, so your interpretation is correct. In fact, there is no such function. If $f$ was such a function, then $g(z) = f(z) - z$ would be in the same class with $g(x+iy) = x^2-x$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$. However, this would mean that $g$ maps the unit circle onto the real interval $[-1/4,2]$. By the open mapping principle, $G = g(\mathbb{D})$ is open, so $\partial G \subseteq g(\partial \mathbb{D})= [-1/4,2]$. By the maximum principle $G$ is contained in the disk centered at $0$ of radius $2$. However, there is no domain $G$ satisfying both of these properties.